# Get body request in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have the following AWS Lambda running NodeJs 8.0 which receives requests from API Gateway.

Lambda code looks the following:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("event.body = " + event.body);
    console.log("event.body.requestType = " + event.body.requestType);
    .  
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This line:

```
console.log("event.body = " + event.body);
```

prints the following (in Cloudwatch)

```
2019-03-10T16:58:31.265Z    276b4902-e716-44b1-ad9e-ed4eb4e1c02d    event.body =
{
    "requestType": "single",
    "createdAt": "2019-03-10T16:58:29.722",
}
```

I want to get the value of requestType, so trying to do the following:

```
console.log("event.body.requestType = " + event.body.requestType);
```

but it prints

```
event.body.createdAt = undefined
```

How can I get the requestType value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the body is an encoded string, try this:

```
console.log("event.body.requestType = " + JSON.parse(event.body).requestType);
```